# How to modify all elements of the same type through get.ElementByTag()

Tags: javascript

I want to modify all input texts of my document by removing their last letter. For example. I have paragraph 1 and 2.

```
1="Hello"; 
2= "Bye".
```

I would like to create a button that executed the function `getElementByTag()`, then pick all the paragraphs and transform them into "Hell" and "By" through the pop function

I guess that is the correct function if I am not wrong.

How could I do that? Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? If you can provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it can help a lot, not only yourself but others trying to help you.

Comment: Asking for direct answers to your problem isn't going to help you in your career. try something first and then if you face issues then ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example

```js
document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener('click', () => {
  let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
  let elementsArray = Array.from(elements)
  elementsArray.forEach(element => {
    element.innerText = element.innerText.slice(0, -1)
  })
})
```

```html
<p> Word </p>
<p> Bye </p>
<button id="remove">Remove!</button>
```

You would use `getElementsByTagName`. That function returns a node list (Not a JS Array) which you have to convert to an array with `Array.from()`. Then you use `Array.forEach` to loop over the elements and use `innerText.slice(0, -1)` to remove the last letter.

Documentation:

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through all of the elements.

Try

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p').forEach(e => {
   let text = e.innerText;
   e.innerText = text.substring(0, text.length - 1));
}
```